# How to programmatically tell browser to automatically allow pop-ups in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo

When I launch a new window, tab, in OpenERP (code included), Firefox browser blocks the launch. I know that I can allow pop-ups in Firefox setting, but I don't want to do that. I want to, programmatically, tell any browser to allow me, automatically, to launch a new window in the new tab. Any suggestions how to do that?

Here is the code that launches a new window:

```
class mrp_bom_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom.line'

    def action_go(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        bom_obj = self.pool.get('mrp.bom')
                action_obj = self.pool.get('ir.actions.act_window')
                id_s = action_obj.search(cr, uid,  [('name', '=','Bill of Materials' ), ('context', '=','{}' )])
                for rec in action_obj.browse(cr, uid, id_s, context=context):    
                        action = rec.id 
        url = '/web#id=%s&view_type=form&model=mrp.bom&action=' + str(action)
        for bom_line in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            if bom_line.product_id.default_code > '300':
                bom_ids = bom_obj.search(cr, uid, [('product_id', '=', bom_line.product_id.id)], context=context)
                if bom_ids:
                                        return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_url', 
                        'res_model': 'ir.actions.act_url',
                        'url':url % bom_ids[0] , 
                        'nodestroy': True, 
                        'target': 'new_tab'}


        return True
```

Comment: If blocking pop-ups can be disabled programmatically then it defeats the purpose of having this pop-up blocking feature. Even if you can override it, there are third party pop-up blocker such as AdBlock, though this could be targeting Ads only.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, the purpose of the popup blockers is to protect web users from web developers and its invasive popups.

If there was a way to disable blockers, everybody will use it (for advertising purposes mainly).

So to answer your question, no there is no way.